# md-select options still visible when closing md-dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material, md-select

I have a `md-dialog` with two `md-select` directives in it. When I hit the md-select then close the dialog, the options are still visible..

I searched on google and github but I can't find any information on this behaviour.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate what I mean :

[image: First]

And that's what happen when I click on cancel :

[image: Second]

I'm using angular material V1.1.1

Comment: check your browser console, is there any error ?

Comment: Nothing related to that behaviour.

Comment: which version of material you are using? Material2 does not seem to have this behavior.

Comment: Question edited with the version

Comment: @Faisal I'm using AngularJS So I can't really use Material2 I think.

Comment: Instead of debugging which can be difficult for this particular third party library, you can have  a close icon on this select. Second, you can use a simple select instead of angular material's . There are many cross browser issues too that you would come across.Content inside the modal's being the most frustrating ones.